# Drawing a Discrete number of rects in an svg element.using D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, data-visualization

js and I am trying to figure out how to draw a discrete number of rectangles in an SVG element. It could be 5 rectangles to a million. What is the best way to go about this? Should I be using the Ordinal scale since I have a discrete number of rectangles or should I be using the linear scale? So I'm thinking that the width of the rectangles should shrink as the number of rectangles grows larger.

Comment: Do you want to place the rectangles next to each other? On top of each other? Drawing a million rectangles will be too slow, you can maybe scale up to a few thousand.

Comment: next to each other, before I was using width/(d3.range(number of rects).length) + xmargin for the width attribute and using the same thing for the position of the x value, but I'm using 1 2 3 4 5... to move it over so it doesn't overlap. I was trying to figure out how to do it with scales but failed.

Comment: Have you tried having just a linear scale with the indices as input domain and the x starting positions a output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the layout and create the appropriate scales. For example:

```
var width = 300,
    height = 20,
    margin = 2,
    nRect = 20,
    rectWidth = (width - (nRect - 1) * margin) / nRect,
    svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
       .attr('width', width)
       .attr('height', height);

var data = d3.range(nRect),
    posScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data))
        .range([0, width - rectWidth]);

svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', posScale)
    .attr('width', rectWidth)
    .attr('height', height);
```

I wrote a small jsfiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/pnavarrc/CA7rY/

Comment: Thanks would there be a good way to do this if I wanted a square matrix?